# Highcharts Bar Graph Remove Category when all bar values for category equal 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I remove a category when all the bar values for a category equal 0

See: (http://jsfiddle.net/no1uknow/EJFsH/1/)

If only one bar equals 0, it should NOT remove the bar.
But if ALL 3 bars equal 0 then the category should be removed.

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'blue'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -100,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'gray',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to filter the data before initializing the chart like so:

```
var data = [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
    name: 'Year 1900',
    data: [0, 156, 947, 408, 6]
}, {
    name: 'Year 2008',
    data: [0, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
}];

data = $.grep(data, function (category) {
    return $.grep(category.data, function (item) {
        return item > 0;
    }).length > 0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EJFsH/2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you would like to dynamically remove categories (by setting them by setCategories function) you also should take care about elements in data series. In other words, when you would like to modify categories, you should also remove data points. Will be better to prepare data without zero, before you use data in highcharts.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian I ended up reconstructing my data before hand as you suggested... Justin does have an awesome solution above, but I already released my code... thank again!